# Chrome Extensions - How can i perform an action, when chrome.browserAction.onClicked has fired?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a browserAction extension, with an icon and a listener on it.

I have a manifest file, and a background script, the script is the following:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:'some code here'});
});
```

The code works on the page, i tried it on a different way (popup and a button what fires the action). But if i try it with a browserAction onclick method, nothing happens:(

The manifest:

```
{
  "name": "somename",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "sometext",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_title": "MyStyle"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/code.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",  
    "https://www.examplesite.ex/*",
    "http://www.examplesite.ex/*",
    "http://*.ex/*"
  ]
}
```

Can anybody help me?:/

Comment: The code is working correctly, provided that you click the button at one of the URIs as mentioned at the `permissions` section. When the button is clicked at another location (eg. `about:blank`), the following expected error will show up: `"Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error."`

Comment: But for me, when i visit one site of the allowed ones, and click to the icon.., nothing happens. For example, code injected is really simple: **'document.title="newtitle";'** Although, title does not change! :(

Comment: Are the match patterns really valid? Go to `chrome://extensions/`, Developer mode, and open the console for the background page. Does any error show up?

Comment: hmm.. i made the extension at job, and now, as i arrived home, i launched the extension, and its going :O strange. Thanks for the help by the way. :) Next step to make it automatic, without any click, i think it will be a page action.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the original question has been solved in the comments, I'll answer the follow-up question:
>   *"Next step to make it automatic, without any click"*.

This can be done easily using [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). When you don't have to access global variables, the following code is sufficient. Otherwise, inject the script using the techniques as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script):

#### `js/code.js`

```
document.title = "newtitle";
```

#### [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html)

```
{
  "name": "somename",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "sometext",
  "content_scripts": {
    "js": ["js/code.js"],
    "matches": [ "*://www.examplesite.ex/*", "http://*.ex/*" ]
  },
  "permissions": [ "*://www.examplesite.ex/*", "http://*.ex/*" ]
}
```